# Adding a derived column on an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Derived/calculated column on existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908456/derived-calculated-column-on-existing-table)

I have SQL Server table with values, as follows:

```
Account - Date - Amount - Summary
10000 - 2010-1-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10000 - 2010-2-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10000 - 2010-3-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10000 - 2010-4-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10000 - 2010-5-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10000 - 2010-6-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10000 - 2010-7-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10000 - 2010-8-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10000 - 2010-9-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10000 - 2010-10-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10000 - 2010-11-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10000 - 2010-12-1 - 50.00 - 600.00
10001 - 2010-1-1 - 50.00 - 0.00
10001 - 2010-2-1 - 60.00 - 0.00
10001 - 2010-12-1 - 60.00 - 170.00
```

This is a basic snapshot of the table. The "summary" field gives the total for the amounts at the end of the year on the date column, but only when the MONTH(Date) = '12'. It goes on this way for hundreds of accounts, with about 4 more years as well. I would like to add a column to this existing table, called "SummaryPreviousYear". The SummaryPreviousYear column should have the sum of the amounts from MONTH(Date) = '12' and the previous year. I'd like to join this column on the account number, so that it sits next to the Summary column and gives a value just like the Summary value does. Can anyone help me with this? I am pulling my hair out here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it not sufficient to query the information for "2010-12-1" for the account when looking at the summary for "2011-12-1"? A simple "decrement year by 1 and get the summary from that entry" type thing.. why have another column? Even the current "Summary" column is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that `[Account]` and `[Date]` are unique, simply `JOIN` onto the same table like this:

```
SELECT
    a.* -- you should explicitly list the columns you want, though
    ,b.[Summary] SummaryPreviousYear
FROM
    myTable a
JOIN
    myTable b
        ON b.[Account] = a.[Account]
        AND DATEPART("yyyy" , b.[date] ) = DATEPART("yyyy" , a.[date] ) - 1
        AND DATEPART("mm" , b.[date] ) = 12
        -- AND whatever other conditions define unique rows
```

There should be no more than one row having the year-1 and month 12, for any data point. If you want `NULL` values for the first-year rows, make this a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead.

Comment: you are missing a AND DATEPART("mm" , a.[date] ) = 12

Comment: Matthew PK, thank you, this self-join query offers a lot of insight. However, account and date are not unique. There is a "location" column. The combination of location, account, and date are unique. I am getting redundant values. :/

Comment: This is an edited form of the question, with needed details...sorry I didn't include them first time around http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1343604-392-1.aspx?Update=1

Comment: @Deep then you simply `JOIN` the rows based on all of the values which guarantee uniqueness to the date. Your original request did not mention a `location` column.

Comment: @Blam that is not the requirement I understood? I thought **each row** should have the value from December of the prior year, not just December of the current year.